# Julia: accumulating an array in a for loop (problem of local scope of loops)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, scope, julia, accumulate

I'm running into the problem of accumulating an array with a for-loop (my array is called `condition_list`, and each row stores a unique configuration of parameters).

The code below is what I'm imagining for building this array:

```
param1_vals = [1.0f0 2.0f0 3.0f0]; # specific values here don't matter
param2_vals = [1.0f0 2.0f0 3.0f0]; # specific values here don't matter
param3_vals = [1.0f0 2.0f0 3.0f0]; # specific values here don't matter

condition_list = zeros(Float32, 1, 3) # initialize condition_list

for ii = 1:length(param1_vals)
        for jj = 1:length(param2_vals)
                for kk = 1:length(param3_vals)
                        row_to_stack = [param1_vals[ii], param2_vals[jj], param3_vals[kk])
                        condition_list = vcat(condition_list, row_to_stack)
                end
         end
end

condition_list = condition_list[2:end,:] # pop off that first row (leftover of the initialization)
```

So each row of the resulting `condition_list` should have a unique configuration of each of the values of `param1_vals` , `param2_vals` , and `param3_vals`.

The issue I'm running into is about scope of local variables -- I get a `condition_list is not defined` error at the inner most line of the loop, when using `vcat`. What's the most Julian way to approach this problem, if I can't use an array accumulation? Or perhaps there's some solution using `push!` or something?

Also, is there a way you can accumulate an array without doing the stupid 'pop off the first row 'thing I did at the end? Can you start with a zero-row, 3 column array and accumulate rows onto it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first comment is that maybe it is enough for you to have a lazy iterator of tuples. In this case it is enough if you write:

```
res = Iterators.product(param1_vals, param2_vals, param3_vals)
```

However, if you really need a matrix then run the following code on `res`:

```
mapreduce(x -> hcat(x...), vcat, res)
```

Now if you really wanted to work with something that you do in your code I would go with:

```
condition_vec = Matrix{Float32}[]

for ii = 1:length(param1_vals)
        for jj = 1:length(param2_vals)
                for kk = 1:length(param3_vals)
                        row_to_stack = [param1_vals[ii] param2_vals[jj] param3_vals[kk]]
                        push!(condition_vec, row_to_stack)
                end
         end
end

condition_list = reduce(vcat, condition_vec)
```

However, this code is a bit over-complicated as you could simply do:

```
condition_vec = Matrix{Float32}[]
for p1 = param1_vals, p2 = param2_vals, p3 = param3_vals
    push!(condition_vec, [p1 p2 p3])
end
condition_list = reduce(vcat, condition_vec)
```

without intermediate indexing.

Finally your code is not working as `condition_list` is a global variable and you would have to write:

```
global condition_list = vcat(condition_list, row_to_stack)
```

to make it work (note that there is a change coming to Julia and soon this will not be needed; this comment is for current 1.4.2 release of Julia, or other releases post 1.0 release).

Finally note that:

```
row_to_stack = [param1_vals[ii], param2_vals[jj], param3_vals[kk])
```

is an incorrect syntax (you used `)` not `]` at the end of the line).
Also you use `,` not just spaces as in my code to separate values which would create you a column vector (not a matrix with 1-row as this is I guess what you wanted from your use of `zeros` function).

If you would have more questions regarding this code please ask in the comment.

Comment: Or perhaps `mapreduce(Base.splat(hcat), vcat, res)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation and the alternative options! I think I will go with the iterator-of-tuples method that you first suggested. The problem is that I have very little experience with the `Iterators` functions in Julia, so if you will entertain me, one more quick question:

I want to iterate over these 'parameter configurations' (formerly, the rows of the `condition_list` matrix). How do I get one tuple (param configuration) from the iterator object ( `res` above)? As of now, I can only see the individual tuples if I print them in a for-loop (`for cond_i in res`).

Comment: The point of `Iterators` is that it is lazy (i.e. it does not allocate any memory). The drawback is that it is not materialized, i.e. you cannot call `getindex` on it, but you need to access them iteratively (e.g. using `for` loop). If you would like to be able to do indexing, then just run `collect(res)` and you will get a materialized array and you can easily index into it.